# Imprecise raycast with orthographic camera in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting, orthographic

I'm developing a 2d viewer of CAD drawings using the three.js library and for this project I need to be able to click the objects in the scene to do some operations.

Using orthographic camera the three.js raycasting is not precise as I expect.

Here the code and a fiddle that shows exactly what I mean
https://jsfiddle.net/toriphes/a0o7td1u/

```
var camera, scene, renderer, square, raycaster;
init();
animate();

function init() {

  output = document.getElementById('output');

  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  // Renderer.
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Add renderer to page
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // Create camera.
  var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  var d = 20;
  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, -window.innerHeight / 2, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 10;
  camera.position.x = 25;
  camera.position.y = 25;
  camera.zoom = 10
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enableRotate = false
  controls.target.x = camera.position.x;
  controls.target.y = camera.position.y;

  controls.update();


  // Create scene.
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var points = [
    new THREE.Vector2(10, 10),
    new THREE.Vector2(40, 10),
    new THREE.Vector2(40, 40),
    new THREE.Vector2(10, 40),
    new THREE.Vector2(10, 10)
  ]

  var shape = new THREE.Shape(points);

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().setFromPoints(points);

  var square = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xFF0000
  }));
  scene.add(square)

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', findIntersections, false);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function updateMousePosition(event) {
  return new THREE.Vector3(
    (event.clientX - renderer.domElement.offsetLeft) /
    renderer.domElement.clientWidth *
    2 -
    1,
    -(
      (event.clientY - renderer.domElement.offsetTop) /
      renderer.domElement.clientHeight
    ) *
    2 +
    1,
    0
  );
}

function findIntersections(e) {
  var mouseposition = updateMousePosition(e);
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouseposition, camera);
  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
  output.innerHTML = intersects.length > 0 ?
    'Intersect: TRUE' :
    'Intersect: FALSE';
}
```

If you pass the mouse near the red square you can see that the intersection trigger before hovering the edge.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intersection detection of lines depends on the [`.linePrecision`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.linePrecision) property of the [`Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.linePrecision).

e.g.

```js
raycaster.linePrecision = 0.1;
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
```

The parameter has to be set dependent on the scale of the scene. The value of 0.1 is an empirical value, which gives good results for your example. Sadly there is not further information provided in the documentation (perhaps I've overlooked something, but I didn't find one).

Comment: `linePrecision = 0.1` seems to work in my project.

it would be useful to have a little more documentation about it.

Comment: Great tip. I use value 0.01 which gives me the accuracy I want.  But presumably it means the raycaster has to do 10x10=100 times more work than when using value 0.1. |True, the linePrecision property isnt mentioned at [offical docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster). But mentioned there is the `params` object within which `threshold`  is the precision of the raycaster when intersecting various objects, in world units.It explains why it was sometimes hard to pick mesh objects when line objects had a default threshold of 1.